# Button var to clipboard

Tags: javascript, api, button

In the funtion below there is this var link. By clicking on the button I want to copy the var to clipboard.

```
function displayUser(user) {
    
var text = `Account No.: ${user.userId} <br> Country: ${user.country} <br> 
 "<button onclick="copyToClipboard(link)"> Copy Link</button>"`;
var link = `${user.Url}`;

grid.innerHTML += text;
}

function user(data) {
    data.result.roomList.forEach((user) => displayUser(user));
}
```

What I found here and tried is this funktion:

```
function copyToClipboard(link){
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    dummy.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=link;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```

By clicking on the button it says "link is not defined". Anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `copyToClipboard(link)` won't work because you're declaring `link` as local variable inside your function. In the outer scope of the button being clicked, it isn't visible. You also have `"` quotes around your <button>, these will appear on your page. A quick fix is to put `let link;` at the top of your script, then remove `link` from your onclick call and function declaration: `onclick="copyToClipboard()">` and `function copyToClipboard() {`. You now also need to remove the `var` from `var link = user.Url;`

Comment: Also note that the function you're using is obsolete, you can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

Answer (score 1):

This section here should be:

```
function displayUser(user) {
    
    var link = user.Url;
    var text = `Account No.: ${user.userId} <br> Country: ${user.country} <br> 
    "<button onclick="copyToClipboard('${link}')"> Copy Link</button>"`;

    grid.innerHTML += text;
}

function user(data) {
    data.result.roomList.forEach((user) => displayUser(user));
}
```

The variable **link** was not accessible, because you defined it after, and also you did not enclose it correctly

---

I've changed this section:

```
... onclick="copyToClipboard('${link}')" ...
```

Because when the function is called, it is called with the actual value as the parameter, so when enclosed in quotes it will act as a string

Comment: For testing and to see if the link is the problem I replaced `var link = user.Url;` with `var link = user.country;`. By clicking the button now it says "United States is not defined" (for example). So the main thing seems to work but now there is this problem. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Ok, check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. This didn't make the copying to clipboard work, but that's how you can pass it to the function like you want it.

```
function displayUser(user) {
    
    var grid = document.getElementById("testgrid");
    console.log(grid);

    var link = `${user.Url}`;
    var text = `Account No.: ${user.userId} <br> Country: ${user.country} <br> 
     <button onclick="copyToClipboard('${link}')"> Copy Link</button>`;
    
    grid.innerHTML += text;
}
    
function user(data) {
    data.result.roomList.forEach((user) => displayUser(user));
}

function copyToClipboard(link){
    console.log(link);
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    dummy.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=link;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}

displayUser({Url: "bla", country: "blabla"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the version of Cypherjac looking like this now. I don't get an error anymore but also no result in the clipboard.

```
function displayUser(user) {

var link = user.Url;
var text = `Account No.: ${user.userId} <br> Country: ${user.country} <br> 
<button onclick="copyToClipboard(${link})"> Copy Link</button>`;

grid.innerHTML += text;
}

function user(data) {
  data.result.roomList.forEach((user) => displayUser(user));
}

function copyToClipboard(link){
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    dummy.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=link;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

Then I tried the suggestions of Chris G looking like this now. But also no error and no result. Any more ideas?

```
let link;               
            
function displayUser(user) {
    
var text = `Account No.: ${user.userId} <br> Country: ${user.country} <br> 
 "<button onclick="copyToClipboard()"> Copy Link</button>"`;
link = user.Url;

grid.innerHTML += text;
}

function user(data) {
    data.result.roomList.forEach((user) => displayUser(user));
}

function copyToClipboard(){
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    dummy.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=link;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another alternative, I will provide one that I've used before and it works.

So the function has a fallback for other browsers as well, so it has support for Edge, Chrome and Firefox ... IE maybe and maybe not

On the click of a button with the style provided when initializing the function: `new clipboardHandler('copy-exec')`, it triggers a document **copy** function to select the element which is the `previousSibling` of the element

You can of course tweak it to your needs.

Then also **NOTE**: The 2 elements are placed back to back in the `HTML`. That's because if you put any space between them, the **previousSibling** of the element becomes that element, which is basically a `non-breaking space` character

But once you change the target element: `previousSibling`, it will work according to your needs

```js
function clipboardHandler(c){
  function copy_relative_text(node){
    if(document.body.createTextRange){
      const range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(node);
      range.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    else if(window.getSelection){
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(node);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    else {
      console.warn("Could not select text in node");
    }
  }
  function clear_selection(){
    if(window.getSelection){
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
      document.selection.empty();
    }
  }
  this.clipboard_target = function(){
    var clips = document.getElementsByClassName(c);
    for(var i = 0; i < clips.length; i++){
      clips[i].onclick = function(){
        copy_relative_text(this.previousSibling);
        setTimeout(() => {
          clear_selection();
        }, 500);
        this.innerHTML = 'Copied';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.innerHTML = 'Copy Link';
        }, 2000);
      };
    }
    return this;
  };
}

let clip = new clipboardHandler('copy-exec')
clip.clipboard_target()
```

```css
.copy-text {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.copy-exec {
  background-color: teal;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p class="copy-text">I will be copied to your clipboard!!!</p><button class="copy-exec">Copy Link</button>
```

Comment: I think this is a bit too much over my head, but thanks anyways, really appreciate it.